# Vue.js app not throwing errors to console from specific methods

Tags: javascript, npm, error-handling, vuejs2, vue-router

I am currently developing 2 Vue apps. Both of them run from npm.
App1 wasn't created by me. I got involved in it when it was already a stable production app (so I may have missed some configuration).
App2 was created by me and I'm the only developer.

In both apps I use vue-router to change views and I found 2 different situations:

1. When I run both apps locally (with npm): App2 throws errors (to
   console) from vue-router when I try to navigate to the same view
   (Navigation Duplicated), but App1 doesn't.
2. When I run both apps on server (online): Both apps throw this error to
   console.

I know what the error is about, but what I don't know is why App1 doesn't throw it. I already searched App1 for any error catching methods, which maybe were implemented to not throw the errors, but I didn't find any.

Because of difference between local/server functionality, I don't think it's a vue-router issue, but rather Vue itself, because there's also second issue with App1. 
In App1 I use vee-validate and it throws errors regarding not available validation items (Validating a non-existent field: "result". Use "attach()" first.). The error can only be seen online (server), but not locally (npm) - for me it confirms it (as I didn't find any error catching methods regarding vee-validate).

**Is there any setting in Vue, which could cause the errors not to be thrown to console?**

Edit:
Reproduction of error: To reproduce and throw vue-router NavigationDuplicated error you should implement  component in your Vue app and click it twice. The first click should navigate you to view, the second click should throw error in console.

Comment: a [mcve] please?

Comment: Added example of how to reproduce vue-router error.

Comment: that is not a [mcve]

Comment: I have the same issue. Any obvious error in a computed property is not being shown in the console. Even a deliberate console.error() is not printed.

Comment: Just discovered that the component using that computed property was not rendered because of a condition. I removed that condition and errors started showing up. If that helps at all.